# How to get IP of backend selected?

Tags: haproxy

I am using HAProxy with multiple backends and some ACLs to select a backend, I want my client (for testing purposes and etc) to know the ip of the backend that was selected.

For example, Client sends request to HAProxy which loadbalances between ip A and ip B. In the response header, I want the ip of A if A was selected by HAProxy and I want the ip of B if B was selected. I know of %[dst] but it returns the ip of the HAProxy server instead.

Right now I'm putting `http-response set-header X-Forwarded-Host %[dst]:%[dst_port]` in the frontend and it is returning the ip and port of the HAProxy

Comment: found the answer, its %si:%sp. http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8.2.4

Comment: Please post your answer as a full answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer, its %si:%sp. cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#8.2.4

Comment: Can you post your full configuration? I have the same problem, but the suggested `%si:%sp` header doesn't work.